# Picovoice: Initialization failed - not able to set the variable 'started' to true

Tags: java, android

I am using the library [Picovoice](https://github.com/Picovoice/picovoice) on Android as a service.

```java
public class PicovoiceService extends Service {
    private final String ACCESS_KEY = "MyAccessKey"; // AccessKey obtained from Picovoice Console (https://picovoice.ai/console/)

    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "PicovoiceServiceChannel";

    private PicovoiceManager picovoiceManager;

    private final PicovoiceWakeWordCallback picovoiceWakeWordCallback = () -> {
        Notification n = getNotification("Picovoice", "Wake Word Detected...");

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.notify(1234, n);
    };

    private final PicovoiceInferenceCallback picovoiceInferenceCallback = inference -> {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        if (inference.getIsUnderstood()) {
            builder.append(inference.getIntent()).append(" - ");
            final Map<String, String> slots = inference.getSlots();
            if (slots.size() > 0) {
                for (String key : slots.keySet()) {
                    builder.append(key).append(" : ").append(slots.get(key)).append(" ");
                }
            }
        } else {
            builder.append("Didn't understand the command.");
        }

        Notification n = getNotification("Picovoice", builder.toString());

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.notify(1234, n);
    };

    private final PicovoiceManagerErrorCallback picovoiceManagerErrorCallback = error -> {
        onPicovoiceError(error.getMessage());
    };

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Picovoice",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        createNotificationChannel();

        String keywordFilePath = intent.getStringExtra("keywordFileName");
        String contextPath = intent.getStringExtra("contextFileName");

        boolean started = false;

        try {
            picovoiceManager = new PicovoiceManager.Builder()
                    .setAccessKey(ACCESS_KEY)
                    .setPorcupineModelPath("porcupine_params_de.pv")
                    .setRhinoModelPath("porcupine_params_de.pv")
                    .setKeywordPath(keywordFilePath)
                    .setPorcupineSensitivity(0.7f)
                    .setWakeWordCallback(picovoiceWakeWordCallback)
                    .setContextPath(contextPath)
                    .setRhinoSensitivity(0.25f)
                    .setInferenceCallback(picovoiceInferenceCallback)
                    .setProcessErrorCallback(picovoiceManagerErrorCallback)
                    .build(getApplicationContext());
            picovoiceManager.start();
            started = true;
        } catch (PicovoiceInvalidArgumentException e) {
            onPicovoiceError(
                    String.format(
                            "%s\nEnsure your AccessKey '%s' is a valid access key.",
                            e.getLocalizedMessage(),
                            ACCESS_KEY));
        } catch (PicovoiceActivationException e) {
            onPicovoiceError("AccessKey activation error");
        } catch (PicovoiceActivationLimitException e) {
            onPicovoiceError("AccessKey reached its device limit");
        } catch (PicovoiceActivationRefusedException e) {
            onPicovoiceError("AccessKey refused");
        } catch (PicovoiceActivationThrottledException e) {
            onPicovoiceError("AccessKey has been throttled");
        } catch (PicovoiceException e) {
            onPicovoiceError("Failed to initialize Picovoice " + e.getMessage());
        }

        Notification notification = started ?
                getNotification("Picovoice", "Listening...") :
                getNotification("Picovoice init failed", "Service will shutdown");

        startForeground(1234, notification);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void onPicovoiceError(String message) {
        Intent i = new Intent("PicovoiceError");
        i.putExtra("errorMessage", message);
        sendBroadcast(i);
    }

    private Notification getNotification(String title, String message) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this,
                0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class),
                0);

        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        try {
            picovoiceManager.stop();
        } catch (PicovoiceException e) {
            Log.e("Picovoice", e.toString());
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

When that service gets started, I get the notification

> Picovoice init failed
>
> Service will shutdown

That is because `started` is set to *false*. When debugging, I never get to that point where `started` is getting set to *true*. Why?

My AccessKey is correct but when trying to debug, I get the exception

> ai.picovoice.picovoice.PicovoiceInvalidArgumentException:
> Initialization failed.

Please note, that I have just edited some details on that code since most of the code is from author himself. See the [original code](https://github.com/Picovoice/picovoice/blob/master/demo/android/Service/picovoice-service-demo-app/src/main/java/ai/picovoice/picovoicedemoservice/PicovoiceService.java) (demo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was `setRhinoModelPath("porcupine_params_de.pv")`. That should be replaced with `setRhinoModelPath("picovoice_params_de.pv")`.